# How to write Google and Facebook login in same activity?

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

How can I write google and facebook login in the same activity, I got a conflict between 2 functions onActivityResult

[Google onActivityResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9XbB.png)

[Facebook onActivityResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKQxq.png)

I found the way, its really easy just check if requestCode equals 100 then google login else 100 is facebook login

```
       // RC_SIGN_IN = 100
       if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    } else {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Comment: there is only one `onActivityResult` method to override, so you should put both snippets in one `onActivityResult` method body

Comment: @snachmsm I will try it

Comment: and pass differnt request kye for both to get result